# How to Host Docker Daemon and Docker client in separate machine

Tags: docker, devops

I would like run all the Docker container in reserved server and i want manage the server from my local machine. Is there any way can we achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Using a container orchestration tool like Kubernetes

Answer (score 5):

It's explained in detail in the [docker documentation](http://By%20default,%20Docker%20runs%20via%20a%20non-networked%20Unix%20socket.%20It%20can%20also%20optionally%20communicate%20using%20an%20HTTP%20socket.). By default, Docker runs via a non-networked Unix socket (not exposed). But it can also optionally communicate using an HTTP socket. If you want to keep this safe you need to configure TLS.

I can copy all the commands from the doc page but I think it explains it very well.

In short:

- You have to create CA private and public keys on your server (where
  the daemon is running).
- You can create a server key and a csr from your CA.
- Sign the publickey with your CA
- Generate the signed certificate from a extensions config file.
- On the client machine (your laptop) create a client key and certificate signing request (csr)
- Make the key suitable for authentication in an extensions config file on your client
- Generate the signed certificate (and remove signing requests)
- Protect your key files with `chmod -v 0400`

Now you can make the Docker daemon only accept connections from clients providing a certificate trusted by your CA:

```
$ dockerd --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=server-cert.pem --tlskey=server-key.pem \
  -H=0.0.0.0:2376
```

On your client you can connect using:

```
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=cert.pem --tlskey=key.pem \
  -H=$HOST:2376 version
```

Where $HOST is the DNS or IP of the machine where your daemon is running